# constantly trying to compress filesystem

Tags: filesystems, compression

is there a filesystem that constantly looks for ways to compress data using a small amount of processing power?

particularly i'm looking for a way to dedupe files within various archives (.bz2, 7z, .zip) across many drives, or otherwise the compression method finding a more efficient way of compressing similar byte streams

i want to be able to copy a file to the new filesystem and then if it's a duplicate byte stream that the compression filesystem would eventually compress it, to the point that it may as well be a symlink

ideally, when first copying a file it wouldn't be compressed, or otherwise a very small amount of compression (level 1) and then gradually reprocessing the file up until maximum compression (level 9) while always having read/write access

filesystem needs to have read-write access at all times for all files

Comment: doesnt exist and never will

Comment: like most of my programming projects, it will exist one day if i get funding, and i'll make it open-source

Comment: This could be accomplished without much effort.  There just isnt a demand for it.

Comment: you're right. with everything going to the cloud, it just isn't economically feasible to have such a filesystem for a nas, but i'll do it anyway. one day.

Comment: its has nothing to do with the cloud.  Simply adding a new drive to a NAS, or upgrading to larger drives provides *immediate* storage.  Compression and data deduplication work.  However, their benefits cant be predicted.  You could spend massive amounts of time compressing and recompressing, deduplicating, for little to no benefit.  Why waste all that time and CPU cylces when you can just slap in some relatively cheap hardware with immediate and predectible results.

Comment: the types of files i want to store are very similar with subtle changes from file to file, but mostly the same. i basically want a large dictionary that can be applied to an entire drive and be updated. for my purposes it would save several tb, and a monthly update of 5tb worth of files could be reduced to a few gb.

Comment: i've realised a more practical approach would be to use 7zip for the entire drive, decompressing and recompressing with each successive monthly update

Comment: this comment thread is getting to long.  However, I do want to say that is a bad idea.  One big archive is one big point of failure.  If the archive gets corrupted you can end up with nothing.  You would want to store that on a ZFS volume with lots of backups.

Comment: Doesn't your question pretty much describe the dedupe feature in Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel-k suggested windows server (2012+) data dedup is what i'm describing, and for all intents and purposes, it's similar to what i'm after; further information is available here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/data-deduplication/install-enable

@keltari suggested zfs, the open-source file system, supporting both compression and data deduplication, and it's exactly what i'm after. i'm now going to experiment with freenas to see the savings on data i can achieve.

Comment: i should note zfs is not exactly the same as openzfs

Comment: data dedupe isn't what i'm after.

dedupe (on filesystems) replicate at the block level, so if the incremental backup changes a large file in multiple places, dedupe won't have much effect.